# Two backgrounds over each other in two divs

Tags: html, css

My code currently looks like this (simplified):

```css
 .bg-img { 
   background: url('../assets/img/pattern.img') repeat; 
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%; 
   }
   
.main-content{ 
  background: radial-gradient(white, black)l;
  opacity: 0,5; 
  }
```

```html
  <div class="bg-img">
      <div class="main-content">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want the class `.bg-img` to have set `background-image` to repeat the given pattern over full screen (width:100%, height:100%) and `.main-content` to have the background set to `radial-gradient(white,black)` to darken the whole `.bg-img` (pattern).

I can display two backgrounds over each other, but the `radial-gradient` does not have influence on the given pattern - white remains white, the black color from gradient is underneath.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can use multiple background but you need to be more clear and provide more code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you mean that your black color is actually transparent?

Comment: Yes I tried doing it in one div with multiple backgrounds property (CSS3), but i can't set opacity of gradient only, so it can't be done like this. I'm saying that my black color is under the image, which I'm providing in the .bg-img div. I want gradient to be set to opacity: 0.5 to cover pattern image (darken it)

Comment: Please share your findings here. We will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`rgba()`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp) can help you with that. This also prevent the children of `.main-content` to inherit the opacity's value when using `opacity: value`

```css
.bg-img {
  background: url('http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/images/tech/687-background-repeat-round.png');
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.main-content {
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0, 0.5));
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I copied your answer but it didn't worked. I had to edit color of my pattern (from straight white to kind-of dark gray) and now I can see the result! It's working :)
but still I don't understand why white pattern couldn't do it

Comment: You mean the value `white`?

Comment: here's link to image from _.bg-img_ background:
https://i.imgur.com/gHKHHfX.png
when i copied your code it was still invisible. I changed color of circles and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.bg-img{ 
    background:   url('https://www.wallsandmurals.com/content/images/thumbs/0000336_sp1043_750.jpeg') repeat; 
    height:100vh; 
    width:100%;
}
.main-content{ 
  background: radial-gradient(white, black);
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
    <div class="main-content">
    </div>
</div>
```